# three.js serverside collision detection error

Tags: javascript, node.js, three.js, collision-detection

Is there a reason why server side usage of three.js 's collision detection should be different from the client side usage? We are using the same scene with the same setup client and server side.

The thing which we are trying todo is determine on the server side if there is collision, with the world. To make this simple we only use 2 boxes for our world. The code used is taken from Lee Stemkoski collision detection example (for which we thank him - it is excellent and clear).

The client side code runs smooth and without trouble, but the serverside code, which is initiated exactly the same way does not detect collisions. 
In our demo the player uses his arrows to move. this movement is sent to the server, which has exactly the same scene as the client. Then the transformations are applied (rotations, position changes etc) and then these new position are sent back. The server and client are in sync up to here. However the client detects the hits with our objects in the world (2 boxes) and the server does not.

Clientside:

```
socket.on("update", function(data){

var delta = clock.getDelta(); // seconds.
var moveDistance = 200 * delta; // 200 pixels per second
var rotateAngle = Math.PI / 2 * delta;   // pi/2 radians (90 degrees) per second
if( data.type == "rot" ){
  MovingCube.rotation.x = data.x;
  MovingCube.rotation.y = data.y;
  MovingCube.rotation.z = data.z;
}
if( data.type == "pos" ){
  MovingCube.position.x = data.x;
  MovingCube.position.y = data.y;
  MovingCube.position.z = data.z;
}

var originPoint = MovingCube.position.clone();

for (var vertexIndex = 0; vertexIndex < MovingCube.geometry.vertices.length; vertexIndex++){        
  var localVertex = MovingCube.geometry.vertices[vertexIndex].clone();
  var globalVertex = localVertex.applyMatrix4( MovingCube.matrix );
  var directionVector = globalVertex.sub( MovingCube.position );

  var ray = new THREE.Raycaster( originPoint, directionVector.clone().normalize() );
  var collisionResults = ray.intersectObjects( collidableMeshList );
    if ( collisionResults.length > 0 && collisionResults[0].distance < directionVector.length() ) 
      console.log(" Hit ");
    }
})
```

serverside code

```
socket.on("update", function(data){

  console.log("updating location");
  var delta = 0.1 ;//clock.getDelta(); // seconds.
  var moveDistance = 200 * delta; // 200 pixels per second
  var rotateAngle = Math.PI / 2 * delta;   // pi/2 radians (90 degrees) per second
  if( data == "A" ){
    MovingCube.rotation.y += rotateAngle;
    socket.emit("update",{"type":"rot","x":MovingCube.rotation.x,"y":MovingCube.rotation.y,"z":MovingCube.rotation.z});
  }
  if( data == "D" ){
    MovingCube.rotation.y -= rotateAngle;
    socket.emit("update",{"type":"rot","x":MovingCube.rotation.x,"y":MovingCube.rotation.y,"z":MovingCube.rotation.z});
  }
  if ( data == "left" ){
    MovingCube.position.x -= moveDistance;
    socket.emit("update",{"type":"pos","x":MovingCube.position.x,"y":MovingCube.position.y,"z":MovingCube.position.z});
  }
  if ( data == "right" ){
    MovingCube.position.x += moveDistance;
    socket.emit("update",{"type":"pos","x":MovingCube.position.x,"y":MovingCube.position.y,"z":MovingCube.position.z});
  }
  if ( data == "up" ){
    MovingCube.position.z -= moveDistance;
   socket.emit("update",{"type":"pos","x":MovingCube.position.x,"y":MovingCube.position.y,"z":MovingCube.position.z});
  }
  if ( data == "down" ){
    MovingCube.position.z += moveDistance;
   socket.emit("update",{"type":"pos","x":MovingCube.position.x,"y":MovingCube.position.y,"z":MovingCube.position.z});
  }

  var originPoint = MovingCube.position.clone();

  for (var vertexIndex = 0; vertexIndex < MovingCube.geometry.vertices.length; vertexIndex++){
  var localVertex = MovingCube.geometry.vertices[vertexIndex].clone();
  var globalVertex = localVertex.applyMatrix4( MovingCube.matrix );
  var directionVector = globalVertex.sub( MovingCube.position );
  var ray = new THREE.Raycaster( originPoint, directionVector.clone().normalize() );
  var collisionResults = ray.intersectObjects( collidableMeshList );
  if ( collisionResults.length > 0 && collisionResults[0].distance < directionVector.length() ) 
    console.log(" Hit ");                
  }
})
```

Any help would be great. This has been eating my time for 2 weeks now, there is no error message and i cannot figure out what it is that is going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Floating point calculations can produce different results on different machines, let me try to find a good article for you.

Here you go, [Floating point determinism](http://gafferongames.com/networking-for-game-programmers/floating-point-determinism/)

Hope it helps

Comment: The same machine does both client and server side, since I run on localhost atm. The same initial vertici are used for the calculation, but somewhere after that it doesn't work. After the server has updated the position, the results are sent to the client, and he does the same calculation. Nodejs is built ontop of the V8 engine, (google chrome) which i also use for the client side testing. I will try using steps of 1 and parsing to an int, but this will still be seen as floating points, due to javascript.

Comment: I would suggest to log the calculations and compare them to see if they are actually the same.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the real problem here is that your server side code probably does not call the render loop from threejs, (which would break of course)

However, the render loop does some additional work for you, it calls the method updateMatrixWorld() on each object -

So serverside, just before doing your raytrace (which uses the world matrix and not the actual position) - just be sure to call

your_objects_you_want_to_raytrace.updateMatrixWorld();

before you do the actual raytrace.

in your case, MovingCube.updateMatrixWorld();